# Markdown - add class to list items

Tags: css, markdown

How can I add a class attribute to a list, when using markdown? For example, what Markdown would generate the following HTML?

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li class="inner-class">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? just have li.inner-class in your css?

Comment: It looks like you've answered your own question with your example above?

Comment: We've been trying to figure out a [consistent markdown attribute syntax over at talk.commonmark.org](http://talk.commonmark.org/t/consistent-attribute-syntax/272)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markdown doesn't allow for CSS classes to be added as it is a text formatting language rather than a coding language. It's mostly used for rich text documents and the conversion to HTML is more of an extra ability rather than what it was built for.

You can still have HTML within your markdown document so something like this is possible

```
Heading
=======

Just a plain paragraph

<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
    <li class="inner-class">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, if you know the exact position of the list item you want to change, you can do it within css with pseudo classes

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  background: lightgrey;
}
ul li:last-child {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

In jekyll v4.2.0 with kramdown I was able to add a class, in my case "error" to a list item, maybe it works also with your markdown parser.

```markdown
My Text, will end with a list.

- ele 1
- ele 2
- {: .error }ele 3
- ele 4
```

Will generate this `html`

```html
<p>My Text, will end with a list.</p>
<ol>
<li>ele 1</li>
<li>ele 2</li>
<li class="error">ele 3</li>
<li>ele 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This works great, thanks!. If you want to add it to the `ul` element, you can also just add it right above the list starts.

Answer (score 0):

Plain "Markdown doesn't allow for CSS classes to be added", but there are some derivatives like [markdown extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/), who allow [you set the id and class attribute on certain elements using an attribute block](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#spe-attr). But these special attribute blocks can be used **only** with:

- headers
- fenced code blocks
- links
- images

Unfortunately not with "your" lists, but maybe you can us it with a link.